# Facebook og:image - multiple images

Tags: html, facebook

I want to display multiple images in facebook's preview when sharing a website.

How can I do this? Can I just define multiple og:image tags?

Here is an example, what I want to do:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a single og:image tag.

```
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="src/to/image/file" />
```

But when you share a link on facebook, they give you the option to add multiple images. Use that option.
[image]

See at the bottom you have the option to add multiple images. Use that and then publish.

> Another Option

You can add multiple og:image tags and then if only single image shows up update that page link in facebook debugger.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="src/to/image/1">
<meta property="og:image" content="src/to/image/2">
```

Any pages that have already been shared (with one image) can be updated by loading the link in the facebook debugger here:

[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/](https://web.archive.org/web/20230120020221/https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

The debugger/linter may not show a preview of all the images – it may just show the last one however it does work.

Comment: Is there a possibility that it'll load multiple images automatically? Because I have a carousel with product images on website. And when someone sharing, it's showing just one image that is in og:image meta tag. But I saw some websites, that when I shared, it automatically loaded multiple images.. Like on yours and mine screenshot

Comment: @kironet I have updated my answer. Just have a look.